# Visual Studio Code no crea líneas en blanco automáticas al presionar Enter

Tags: javascript, css, visual-studio, vscode, ide

Desde hace tiempo ando teniendo este inconveniente en VSCode. Al crear una función, escribir CSS o cualquier otro lenguaje, al presionar enter, las llaves ya no corren hacia abajo y dejan una línea en blanco para seguir escribiendo automáticamente. Lo que me obliga a pulsar siempre doble enter y subir con las teclas de dirección hacia arriba más pulsar el tabulador. Quizá parezca una tontería pero se pierde muchísimo tiempo en hacer el código. No se si a alguien más le habrá pasado. Dejo un ejemplo de lo que os cuento para que quede más claro y visual:

- Lo genera así

```html
const newFunction = () => {
}

h1 {
}
```

- En vez de así:

```html
const newFunction = () => {

}

h1 {
  
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Muchísimas gracias.

PD: Finalmente lo he solucionado eliminando el contenido de "settings.json" y he ido añadiendo las opciones cuando las he ido necesitando.

Comment: Y antes lo hacia?

Comment: Hola. No, comenzó a hacerlo hará un mes. He desactivado todas las extensiones y sigue igual. También he probado a reinstalar y todo sigue igual

Comment: Abre las opciones y busca `AutoIndent` o `Brackets`, tal vez hayas cambiado accidentalmente una de las configuraciones en estas categorías. La opción default de Auto Indent es `full`

Comment: Eso tampoco ha funcionado. Finalmente lo he solucionado de la manera más bruta. He borrado todo 'settings.json' y se ha arreglado, y poco a poco he puesto las opciones que me han ido haciendo falta, estaré atento a los cambios si vuelve a ocurrir para intentar identificarlo. Muchas gracias a todos por vuestro tiempo

Comment: La solución va abajo, en el campo Tu respuesta. Podrás recibir votos positivos por ella e inculso puedes marcarla como aceptada. Así como está, nadie sabrá si tiene solución

Comment: Ah gracias! Es la primera vez que escribo y no lo sabía

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente lo he solucionado eliminando el contenido de "settings.json" para restaurar vscode a valores de fábrica y he ido añadiendo las opciones cuando las he ido necesitando

Comment: De seguro en algún momento por accidente moviste algo del `settings.json` por lo menos ya sabes que si te sucede de nuevo el problema podrá estar allí y será mejor identificarlo

Comment: Sí, esta vez estaré pendiente y en cuanto vuelva a ocurrir iré poco a poco comprobando cual es

Comment: Me pasa lo mismo actualmente, sin embargo hay mucha configuracion que quiero conservar alguna idea de que lo esta generando?